# Ubuntu 64-bit 'No such file or directory' error in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04

Gentlemen,

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit and I would like to write a batch file .sh

just for fun I wrote

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test"
USER_NAME= 'myname'
```

And I typed
chmod +x ./filename

and I execute
./filename

But I keep getting "No such file" for 'echo'

when I type
echo "test"

I see "test"

what am I missing?

Comment: Please paste the exact error you are seeing.

Comment: Did you create the script in Windows, by any chance? You could have an extra CR (0x0d) character in the script. Check by using **od -x** on the script file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `command not found`? I get that when I run your script.

The problem is in the `USERNAME= 'myname'` line: the space between the `=` and the `'` tell `bash` to set `USERNAME` to nothing (unset it), and then run the command `myname`.

Try it without the space; I think you will find it works.

Comment: I removed the space as you said and it did not work either. Matter of fact I commented out the USERNAME line and it cannot execute echo. I still get this error. the error is echo: No such file or directory

Comment: @Gilson Please copy-and-paste the output of `cat filename`, `ls -la filename`, and `./filename` into your original post.

Comment: thank you for helping. cat mine.sh - no output
 ls -la mine.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gilmotta gilmotta 140 Jun 14 17:09 mine.sh
 ./mine.sh
echo: No such file or directory

Comment: @Gilson Please copy-and-paste the *exact* output into your *original post*, via the `edit` link. What you did there cannot be possible. You show via `cat mine.sh` that mine.sh is empty; you then try to run it and it shows `echo: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I agree I have the same behaviour seen by BenjiWiebe: `command not found` and no problem, _of course_, if removed the space in `USER_NAME='myname'`. Gilson please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/768852/edit) and update it, so it could be useful for the other users.

Answer (score 0):

Gentlemen,

I appreciate your help and I was able to fix the problem. When Benji asked me to post the results from 'cat filename' in my case it did not show anything but nano filename was showing that file was NOT empty.
Then I recreated the file using nano editor and now it works. previously I used LibreOffice.

I think the original file has some garbage character that prevents bash to work or some invisible character is part of the command. But a newly created batch works as expected now.

Thanks, again!